# Pygame Pong, Paddle only moves once up and down and ball doesn't move after regen

Tags: python, pong

So i'm trying to create a single player Pong game. I was able to get the ball to move bounce off the screen and come back but when it hits the wall on the left side it regenerates but doesn't move. Also when trying to move the paddle it will only move up like 1 pixel and only move down 1 pixel then it won't move any more up or down other then that. It's hard to explain so here is the code.

```
import sys
import pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 1000, 800
screenColor = 0, 0, 0
outline = 0, 0, 255

paddleOne = pygame.image.load("PONGPADDLE.png")
ball = pygame.image.load("Bullet.png")
ballRect = ball.get_rect()
paddleRect = paddleOne.get_rect()
speed = [1, 1]
paddleOne_x = 980
paddleOne_y = 400
FPS = 1000
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

paddleOnePos_x = 0
paddleOnePos_y = 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                paddleRect.y += 10
                if paddleRect.top > 0:
                    paddleRect.top = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                paddleRect.y -= 10
                if paddleRect.bottom < 800:
                    paddleRect.top = +1

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                paddleRect_y = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                paddleRect_y = 0

    ballRect = ballRect.move(speed)
    if ballRect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]

    if ballRect.top < 0 or ballRect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    if ballRect.left < 0:
        ballRect = ball.get_rect()
    elif ballRect.colliderect(paddleRect):
        speed[1] = -speed[1]


    paddleOne_y += paddleRect.bottom
    paddleOne_y += paddleRect.top

    screen.fill(screenColor)
    screen.blit(paddleOne, (paddleRect.left, paddleRect.top))
    # screen.blit(paddleOne, (paddleOne_x, paddleOne_y))
    screen.blit(ball, ballRect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, outline, ((0, 0), (width, height)), 5)
    pygame.display.flip()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Your whole `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:` block looks strange to me. `paddleRect_y = 0` means that the paddle will reset its position to the top of the screen every time the user releases the up or down button. So it's not too surprising to me that your paddle doesn't move anywhere. Perhaps you were trying to do something like "reset the paddle's _velocity_ to zero when the user releases the key"?

Comment: Your `if paddleRect.top > 0` and `if paddleRect.bottom < 800:` conditions also seem problematic. If you're trying to do bounds checking, I think you need to switch `<` with `>` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the paddle to move as long as an arrow key is held down, and want it to stop moving when the key is released, then you should be altering the paddle's velocity, rather than its position. Example implementation:

```
paddle_y_velocity = 0

while 1:
    if paddleRect.top < 0:
        paddleRect.top = 0
    if paddleRect.bottom > 800:
        paddleRect.bottom = 800

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                paddle_y_velocity -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                paddle_y_velocity += 1

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                paddle_y_velocity = 0

    paddleRect.top += paddle_y_velocity

    ballRect = ballRect.move(speed)
    #etc
```

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed that problem haha. I can't believe I did not see that before

Comment: Also do you have any idea about why it isn't colliding with the paddle. That doesn't seem to be working and when it regenerates the ball doesn't even move